# Error code 1067, SQL state 42000: Invalid default value for 'memberSince' when compiling a table

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, mysql-error-1067

I'm adding a new table to the list of existing tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Counselor (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR (50),
    nickName VARCHAR (50),
    lastName VARCHAR (50),
    telephone VARCHAR (25),
    email VARCHAR (50),
    memberSince DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Execution is interrupted with the following message:

```
Error code 1067, SQL state 42000: Invalid default value for 'memberSince'
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, `'0000-00-00'` is not a valid date. According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

I recommend using `NULL` if you don't have a meaningful default value you can use.

```
CREATE TABLE Counselor (
...
memberSince DATE DEFAULT NULL,
...
```